# How can I retrieve particular array value and store in database in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to retrieve particular array value from the array and store in database.. The array value is stored as follows

```
Array ( [date] => Fri Feb 18 11:13:51 IST 2022 [CardNumber] => 555555XXXXXX4444 [surcharge] => 0.00 [clientcode] => XYZ[scheme] => MASTER [udf15] => null [udf14] => null [signature] => 278db04000d25ddef35b3cfebc96439619b9ffbee62977ad281823f5caf1651d90e1146265e1bb5ff3f7db255c0ccdca8db9a6475db921fe71b6a4f127b73c49 [udf13] => null [udf12] => null [udf11] => null [amt] => 1000.00 [udf10] => null [merchant_id] => 192 [mer_txn] => 0010 [f_code] => Ok [bank_txn] => 0011000000196384118 [udf9] => null [ipg_txn_id] => 11000000196384 [bank_name] => Hdfc Bank [prod] => NSE [mmp_txn] => 11000000196384 [udf5] => null [udf6] => null [udf3] => 9686123989 [udf4] => test [udf1] => ABC[udf2] => abc@gmail.com [discriminator] => DC [auth_code] => 00000 [desc] => SUCCESS )
```

I want to retrieve only date,ipg_txn_id from the array and store it to the database.. I am not getting to retrieve the value from the array in php

Comment: `$array['date']` did you tried this?

Comment: It displays.. Now I have to retrieve values which i want and store in database?

Comment: `$date = $array['date']; $txn_id = $array['ipg_txn_id'];` then do `INSERT INTO table(date, txn_id) VALUES($date, $txn_id)`